# Not able to group x-axis by month in a pyplot chart (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am starting my first "project" ever with python and I need some help.

I am creating a graph with pyplot that shows how my number of connections at Linkedin has grown since I created my account.

I am having trouble trying to group the X-Axis by month and year. The way I have found to group them is not good as it skips those months in which I didn't have any new connection.

I wanted to know if someone knows how can I solve this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/ignaciolorenzoqueralt/Desktop/linkedin.pythonproject/connections_clean.csv")

df.head(2)

def fun(date):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%d %b %Y").strftime("%Y-%m")


df["Connected On"] = df["Connected On"].apply(fun)


df = df.sort_values(by="Connected On")
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df.drop(columns="index",inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={"level_0":"number"},inplace=True)

print(df)

x = df["Connected On"]
y = df["number"]


rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 15,8
plt.plot(x, y, label="Ignacio's nº of Connections")

plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Number of connections")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.legend()
#plt.grid()

plt.show()

Here is what I have coded:
```

Attached to this link (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yIGQGoCcmq0JOD2Im0B8CQ0oT2fqFh5cKxKO5i8_uAU/edit?usp=sharing) you will find a replica without private info of the csv this project is based on.

Thank you very much in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically 2 parts to your question:

1. Group your data (otherwise plotting can cause weird results when there are several entries per month)
2. Plot data and account for "missing values", i.e. months without entries

The first part can be solved with

```
#get unique months --> no duplicate x values
x = df["Connected On"].unique()

#group by months, then take max number for each month
y = df.groupby("Connected On").max()["number"]
```

The second part has to do with the way how matplotlib treats dates. I think in your case, the dates are interpreted as `strings` and therefore each x,y pair is plotted without any linearity on the x axis. To achieve a temporal linearity and continuity, you need to feed matplotlib with complete datetime objects, which can be achieved with

```
x = pd.to_datetime(df["Connected On"].unique())
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @BenB ! I really appreciate your help. You helped me a lot. If possible, I would like to ask you another question:

When I apply the changes you mention, the y axis happens to be grouped by year, not by year - month. How can I change that?

Comment: Glad I could help. I am sorry, but I don't really understand your second question. Do you mean that `y = df.groupby("Connected On").max()["number"]` is not working on months but on years? I had to re-create a small part of your csv file, because I was not allowed to download it. Maybe the differences arose from some changes in my csv file compared to yours.

Comment: Exactly. I don't have labels such as 2016-03, 2016-05. I only have 2016, 2017 and so on. To show it as in your plot, should I modify the .csv file or just change the way I group the data? Thanks again

Comment: Does your dataframe contain the dates in `year-month` or `year` format? Otherwise your `fun` method might not be working with the dates given in your csv.